# Are third party software installed via provisioners available in VHD image

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, packer, vhd

We have a simple ubuntu 16.04 image with jdk8 installed in provisioners section.

- We created a VHD image in Azure
- We launch a VM using the above VHD

The question is when I create the above VM, does JDK 8 get installed only after the VM is launched or was it part of the VM when its launched. Since we want to install large amount of 3rd party software on the VM, we would like to understand when these libraries are installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a template of a VM in Azure, the template contains all the software installed on the VM at the time of creation (of the template). So the JDK is installed already in the template, it **is not** installed after the VM starts up via any sort of desired state configuration or other scripted method.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed JDK on the VM, left it up and running and made an image in Azure, next time you provision new VM in Azure it will have JDK there.